# backbone.js and cross domain scripting

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, backbone.js

I want to work with backbone.js and jquery. The app is supposed to run offline on mobile phones (i.e. "localhost"), there are few calls on a server side backend somewhere in the internet.

What is the best way to realize cross domain requests with backbone.js?

I would like to use JSON, but I could eventually switch back to REST if necessary.

Here's my not very impressive code so far:

```
App.Collections.Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Event,    
   url: 'http://mydomain.com/api/getevents/user_id/1/'
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand "I would like to use JSON, but I could eventually switch back to REST if necessary." - JSON and REST are not either/or things, JSON is a format for serializing data into a string, REST is a web service interface pattern. I'll post an answer, and adjust if you've got any clarifications.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are two ways of allowing cross-domain XMLHttpRequests, which is the method Backbone.js uses to fetch data from a URL. The first is appropriate if you've got control of the server-side of the non-origin domain you're trying to connect to, and involves implenting [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) (or CORS).

To implement CORS, return the 'Origin' part the HTTP `Referer` request header (the bit up to the beginning of the `path`; it should match regex `^.+?\/{2}[^\/]*`) in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header for domains you want to serve to:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.com
```

You might need to override [Backbone.sync](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) in order for the [right settings](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) to be set on the XMLHttpRequest object.

The second option, if you don't have access to the cross-origin server, would be to proxy the requests through your own server (either the origin one or one which enables CORS). Obviously whoever owns the domain you're trying to call mightn't like you doing that, but that is by design - if they don't want you calling your service, they only have one IP address to block, instead of each of your clients' IP.

Comment: wow, that was simple!  Thanx! :-) For me it worked btw with http://mydomain.com without the slash

Comment: No problems! Now if this covers everything, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the "correct answer" feature, Stoive!

Comment: CORS is ie10+, under that you can do a workaround with jsonp and XDomainObject.