# Backbone REST API recommendation / crossdomain

Tags: javascript, api, rest, backbone.js

I am developing a Backbone app which heavily relies on a REST API using ajax/fetch calls.

All my business logic is written in PHP classes using MySQL. For now i am utilizing [FRAPI](http://getfrapi.com/) as the API which works very well for me.

In my development environment I have two virtual hosts:

1. a static HTML/JS client app -> localhost
2. FRAPI API in PHP -> api.local

The problem is that my clients requests are crossdomain (IE and such browser don´t work).

What can I do to keep my client vhost static (no PHP proxy) and not using JSONP?
What RESTful API is typically used for Backbone?

Comment: JSONP is only for GET requests... CORS is probably the simplest way to achieve cross domain POST and GET calls : see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7174902/447074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look here, on how you can achieve cross domain calls...

[backbone.js and cross domain scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486213/backbone-js-and-cross-domain-scripting)

i fear however you will need option 2, presented in the above url...