# How do I authenticate and consume an external api with backbone?

Tags: web-services, backbone.js, basic-authentication

I'm trying to create a very basic little backbone app that displays stats from my company's [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/) account. They have a REST API which authenticates via Basic Auth or oAuth. I seem to be faced with two problems here:

- Authentication
- Cross-origin requests

So I've started with setting the url for my collection to the respective url:

```
var Projects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'https://mycompany.harvestapp.com/projects',
});
```

And I've tried using [this basic auth plugin](https://github.com/fiznool/backbone.basicauth) but I can't tell if that part is working because I'm still getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486213/backbone-js-and-cross-domain-scripting) is similar and has more details that you should take a look at.

But the general idea is this, if you don't have access to the remote server (which I presume you do not with Harvest) then you need to perform the cross-site requests from your own server that you do control, most likely the one you are deploying this backbone app on. That means writing some server-side code (PHP, Node, etc.) to perform the requests (perfectly legal from server side) and then having your client (Backbone app) request from these scripts.

Here is a brief/pseudo-example with php:

**request.php**

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('https://mycompany.harvestapp.com/projects');
?>
```

**projects.js**

```
var Projects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'request.php',
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't written any server-side code yet but it'll probably be node. Thanks!